# IFTTT Webhooks limit

Tags: iot, webhooks, ifttt

**Info** 
I am using IFTTT to send temperature data from my Nordic Thingy 52 to google spreadsheets using a recipe I wrote.
It works great and 13 rows have been written to my sheet.

**Error** 
The temperature measurement interval was every 2 seconds which was too high for IFTTT as I got the following error:

> Error
>  Usage limit exceeded Dec 12 - 4:41 PM  Webhooks
>  If
>   Maker Event "temperature_update", then Add row to Gal Margalit’s
>   Google Drive spreadsheet
>  Tap to view our Troubleshooting Services
>   page to learn about usage limits Hide details

I've gone through every documentation, troubleshooting and faqs they have on the website but I find no numbers on data limit or intervals.
I've increased the measurement interval to be taken every 60 seconds.

**Does anyone know what is the data limit on IFTTT?**

Comment: I could not find any limit documentation, except for https://help.ifttt.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001448453 , but yes, no mentioning of a number... Is the 60 seconds working for you?